# changed public ip address of domain controller now other servers cannot find dc

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have 3 virtual machines. I had to move them to another dedicated server since the company I was using is having so many issue.

The new dedicated server, of course, has new ip addresses.

They are consecutive ip addresses, for example:

```
192.168.1.10 DC
192.168.1.11 Server1
192.168.1.12 Server2
```

Not the ip address but just an example.

All three computers are online with public ip addresses and accessible on the internet. I cannot get the Server1 & 2 to see the new domain controller.

How do I change the DC server ip address on the 2 computers to see the new ip address of the DC now?

This is the message I am getting:

[image]

I have tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and rebooting but no luck.

**EDIT1**

I did a dcdiag on the domain controller and this is what is shows:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig /registerdns

Windows IP Configuration

Registration of the DNS resource records for all adapters of this computer has b
een initiated. Any errors will be reported in the Event Viewer in 15 minutes.

C:\Users\Administrator>DCDiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = DCVM
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DCVM
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host
         388c6ac2-c78f-479c-b8e5-c0cc89b32024._msdcs.mydomain.com could
         not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server
         name, etc.
         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your
         firewall settings.
         ......................... DCVM failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DCVM
      Skipping all tests, because server DCVM is not responding to directory
      service requests.


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : suburbandomain
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... mydomain passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : mydomain.com
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... mydomain.com passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... mydomain.com passed test Intersite
```

**EDIT2**

```
I found this in the domain controllers event viewer:

The dynamic deletion of the DNS record 'DomainDnsZones.mydomain.com. 600 IN A xx.xx.xx.xx' failed on the following DNS server:  

DNS server IP address: xx.xx.xx.xx 
Returned Response Code (RCODE): 1 
Returned Status Code: 9001  

USER ACTION  
To prevent remote computers from connecting unnecessarily to the domain controller, delete the record manually or troubleshoot the failure to dynamically delete the record. To learn more about debugging DNS, see Help and Support Center.  

ADDITIONAL DATA 
Error Value: DNS server unable to interpret format.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have domain controllers on the Internet? How do you do the DNS stuff related to AD?

Comment: We created a domain specific to this server. I'm not sure I understand the question. It was pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Check DNS records. 
Point main DNS server on server1 and server2 to your DC.

Show us output of:
dcdiag /v /c /d /e

Answer (score 0):

Your hosts will try to locate the Active Directory servers by querying the DNS server for `SRV` records. For example, `_ldap._tcp.example.com`. This kind of records use the canonical name to your Domain Controller so their should be no issue.

However `DomainDnsZone.example.com` and `ForestDnsZone.example.com` both reference the IP address of the Domain Controllers. So when changing your Domain Controller IP address, you should also update the DNS entries.

How to setup your DNS zone depends on your Active Directory domain. Windows provides some tools to fix this. Try to run on one Domain Controller the following commands:

```
> dcdiag /fix
> netdiag /fix
```

This should fix your DNS zone.